# How many natural numbers $n$ exist for $n=a^2−b^2−c^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many natural numbers $n≤1000$ cannot be written in the form $a^2−b^2−c^2 \ ;$

where $a$,$b$ and $c$ are non-negative integers subject to condition $a≥b+c$.

How to approach?

Comment: All negative integers $n$ cannot be written in that form. I assume you mean $n \geq 0$?

Comment: @IvanLoh  Done Editing ! Well it was correct in header.

Comment: https://brilliant.org/i/8SEjnB/

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$2n+1=(n+1)^2-n^2-0^2 ;a=n+1,b=n,c=0$

$2n=(n+1)^2-n^2-1^2 ;a=n+1,b=n,c=1$

Comment: The pattern can be easily identified by testing up to some integers $n:a,b,c;  1:1,0,0;2:2,1,1;3:2,1,0;4:3,2,1;5:3,2,0;6:4,3,1;7:4,3,0;8:5,4,1;9:5,4,0;10:6,5,1;$